# Replace array keys with another value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which looks like this:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 152
        [type_id] => 5
        [name] => test 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 153
        [type_id] => 8
        [name] => test 2
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 154
        [type_id] => 13
        [name] => test 3
    )
```

Is there any way I can transform it into the array below?

```
[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 152
        [name] => test 1
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 153
        [name] => test 2
    )

[13] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 154
        [name] => test 3
    )
```

Basically I changed the array key with the type_id value.

Comment: You want to remove type_id key

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: loop + unset(object->type_id)

Comment: Use foreach loop and again assign the values to array.

Comment: Is there any way you can explain me why did you downrated the question ?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to unset the `stdClass`'s properties as follows:

```
$newObject = array();
foreach ($oldObject as $object) {
    $typeID = $object->type_id;
    $newObject[$typeID] = $object;
    unset($newObject[$typeID]->type_id);
}
```

This will iterate through your array of `stdClass` objects and save the entry into a new array. Afterwards, the property `type_id` will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Pass it into a function that returns a new array:

```
function convert($arr)
{
    $new_arr = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
    {
        $id = $arr[$i]['type_id'];
        unset($arr[$i]['type_id']);
        $new_arr[$id] = $arr[$i];
    }
    return $new_arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To replace a value, simply use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php and to add another value: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php